# Hive TimeStamp for Weekly and Quarterly data

Tags: hive

The below hive command,

```
select * from my_new_table
  where month(time_stamp)= '03'
    and year(time_stamp) = '2016'
    and age = '1'
    and gender = '0'
    and income = '4'
    and ethnicity = '3'
    and marital_status = '1';
```

generates the following results for all the data (31 days) for the month of March(03) 2016:

```
time_stamp              age gender  income  ethnicity   marital_status
2016-03-14@17:42:47.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-14@16:10:51.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-20@15:16:44.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-14@17:13:51.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-14@17:12:51.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-14@18:24:51.000 1   0       4       3           1
2016-03-03@13:02:06.000 1   0       4       3           1
```

Similarly, I want to get the data for 2nd quarter of 2016 (or nth quarter, data should come for 3 months, starting March 1st till May 31st for this quarter ) and 12th week (or nth week, data should come for 7 days for this particular week) of 2016. What is the correct Hive command for this?

I'm getting error if I replace `month` with `quarter` or `week` in the Hive command.

```
select * from my_new_table 
where quarter(time_stamp)='03' 
and year(time_stamp) = '2016';
```

returns

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:71 Invalid function 'quarter'
```

and

```
select * from my_new_table 
where week(time_stamp)='12' 
and year(time_stamp) = '2016';
```

returns

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:71 Invalid function 'week'
```

Looks like there needs to be a calculation included in getting the nth quarter or week but not sure. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It may help if you show the commands you've tried and the specific errors that are generated. [Date Functions in Hive](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html) might be informative.

Comment: select * from my_new_table where quarter(time_stamp)='03' and year(time_stamp) = '2016';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:71 Invalid function 'quarter'

select * from my_new_table where week(time_stamp)='12' and year(time_stamp) = '2016';
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:71 Invalid function 'week'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that `month` and `week` functions expect a "string date", not an actual date or timestamp type as input.  You may need to use the `date_format` function to convert your timestamp to a string, then use the functions, like

```
month(date_format(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

This doesn't explain why your first example of these functions as part of the where clause seem to work, however.